# What's the recommended way to pass path params in Angular 2 http object

Tags: angular, http

I am using angular 2, I need to do a delete request to a backend having a path param like this

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

deletePlayer(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete("/api/players/{id}");
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to pass the id path param to the http object. I've used UrlSearchParams for the query parameters but this does not seem to have an option for path params. The docu is not clear about this either.

Comment: You can use `return this.http.delete(\`/api/players/{id}\`);` where `id` should be a variable

Answer (score 6):

You can use [TypeScript template syntax](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html) :

```
return this.http.delete(`/api/players/${id}`);
```

Comment: these are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: What if id contains illegal URL chars? I'm not saying this is a security issue due to "URL Injection" but I would be much happier if Angular2's http module had a URL encoding safe way other than use a template literal...

Comment: Not good solution for URLs defined in environments global variable in JSON format. We can't pass parameters.

Answer (score 5):

You should always escape any string, that might contain non-static values (user inputs, database values, etc.).

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

deletePlayer(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete('/api/players/' + encodeURIComponent(id));
}
```

[`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) will keep you safe.